# ng-src not binding anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to work with angular js and everything works nice, instead of this. I'm binding from an angular list the full image path, like so: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/uploads/1.PNG` , but in inspect element, it shows ng-src, and that's all, not equal, no path, and of course, no image showing up.
What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
<h4 class="card-title">Misiuni</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="ribbon-wrapper card" ng-repeat="mission in missionList">
                        <div class="ribbon ribbon-default"><span ng-bind="mission.missionTitle"></span></div>
                            <p class="ribbon-content"><span ng-bind="mission.missionDesc"></span></p>
                                <center><br><h4 class="card-title">Reward:</h4></center>
                                <center><img ng-src="{{ mission.missionSrc }}"></center>
                                <center><br><h4 class="card-title">Experiență: <span ng-bind="mission.exp"></span></h4></center>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Acceptă misiunea">
                    </div>

                </div>
```

P.S: I double checked, and there's no issue with mission.missionSrc, it holds the correct path of the image.

**web.js**

```
var app = angular.module('web', []);
app.controller('webController', function($scope, $http){

    //$scope.incomeList = [{incomeText: 'Primul income'}];
    $http.get('/api/missions').then(function(response){

        $scope.missionList = [];

        for(var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++){

            var mission = {};
            mission.missionTitle = response.data[i].title;
            mission.missionDesc = response.data[i].description;
            mission.missionSrc = response.data[i].reward;
            mission.exp = response.data[i].exp;
            $scope.missionList.push(mission);

            console.log(mission);

        }


    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the part where mission.missionSrc is processed in your controller ?

Comment: Updated the first post.

Comment: Front-end code looks good. Try to access: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/uploads/1.PNG` and check if return an image.. Maybe the back-end code doesn't allow you to access that folder

Comment: Already did. It shows the image perfectly